# adding libiphone-exif.a to xcode 4

Tags: iphone, exif

i'm trying to read exif data for my app. i found this library, http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/ but can't seem to add it to my project as a framework, it adds it as a text file. does anyone know how to add it?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4, go to the Build Phases tab of your Target settinsg, expand the "Link Binary With Libraries" list, and drag your library there.